# box-python-sdk is not returning total_count for Get Enterprise Users and Get Group

Tags: python-3.x, box-api, boxapiv2

box-python-sdk methods 'Get Enterprise users' and 'Get Group' supports 'Offset-based Paging', according to api [docs](https://developer.box.com/reference) they should return `total_count, limit, offset` fields that can be used for next request/pagination.

```
# sdk method to get enterprise users
users = client.users(limit=1000, offset=0, filter_term=None, user_type=None, fields=fields)  

print(vars(users))  
#output  
{'_session': <boxsdk.session.session.AuthorizedSession object at 0x7f3382a6b400>,  
'_url': 'https://api.box.com/2.0/users', '_limit': 1000,  
'_fields': ['type', 'id', 'name', 'login', 'created_at', 'modified_at',  
       'language', 'timezone', 'space_amount', 'space_used', 'max_upload_size',  
       'status', 'job_title', 'phone', 'address', 'avatar_url', 'role',  
       'tracking_codes', 'can_see_managed_users', 'is_sync_enabled',  
       'is_external_collab_restricted',  'is_exempt_from_device_limits',  
       'is_exempt_from_login_verification', 'enterprise', 'my_tags', 'hostname',  
       'is_platform_access_only'],  
'_additional_params': {'user_type': 'managed'},   
'_return_full_pages': False,   
'_has_retrieved_all_items': False,   
'_all_items': None,   
'_offset': 0}
```

It doesn't return `total_count` and same goes for method `client.get_groups()`.
I have doubled checked `box-api` is returning `total_count`.  am i making some mistake or there is a bug in sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer of this question on github. If anyone else come here googling, I'm posting this for them.

Unfortunately the total_count field is not exposed with the iterator. However, you can get back the total_count if you make a manual call as that returns a JSON object.

Something like this:

`client.make_request('GET', 'https://api.box.com/2.0/users')`.

For more details [click](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/issues/422)